# configurable products in magento not working with shopping cart rules

Tags: magento, discount, configurable-product

I am trying to create rules based on attributes and quantities and am not able to use quantities and attributes in the same rule unless they are both referencing the parent product.

Well this causes a problem since I want to do a quantity of 5 5ml bottles (5ml size is an attribute of the simple product)to trigger a free gift and a discount.

Bigger problem, I have another size bottle that triggers a different discount but because they are all under the same parent products, it doesn't work. The cancel each other out, or I can one to work and not the other.

If anyone has any work around ideas for this I would greatly appreciate it.

Meghan

Comment: The system can't do everything unfortunately, and discounts, tiers, etc in the context of configurables is an area left simple. Fortunately Magento offers a lot of extendability.

Comment: I'm not looking for a perfect or even easy solution just a solution. Any ideas? I'm just looking for opinions on what other people would do next.